# How to send parameters with hyperlink HREF in jade and access it in routes expressJs

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am sending parameter from my jade

```
 a(href="/service-labourJobcardnumber=#{Jobcardnumber}") add labour
```

but it is not treating it as a parameter.How to send the parameter with jade and how can i access it in my index.js routes.
This is my index.js code

```
router.get('/service-labour/:Jobcardnumber', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
    var locals = {};
    console.log(req.params); return;
    locals.Jobcardnumber = req.body.Jobcardnumber;
            res.render('service-labour', locals);
});
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response but i found the answer my mistake was i was using

```
locals.Jobcardnumber = req.params.Jobcardnumber;
```

but it should be

```
locals.Jobcardnumber = req.query.Jobcardnumber;
```